# Newbie Question - speed of footage lags in Premier

Tags: premiere, adobe

I'm using Adobe Premiere to add some graphics that go along with a video we made. The original video was made by someone else, is 2 min long and very HQ and plays well. But once I imported it and worked on it for two days, I didn't realize how slow the frames play in the updated video. It's like the speed of the actors mouths don't move as fast as the audio you hear.

Is there anyway to get the speed back and not drop frames? It does this on my boss's Mac and my laptop.

My graphics aren't very heavy or anything. Just some transparent png images with a few effects.

Comment: (This isn't a solution to your problem, so I'll just post the information as a comment.) In my experience with Premiere, when you import footage it has to "process" it briefly. There is often a blue progress bar at the bottom right of the window that says something about processing or normalizing the footage. Wait until that is done before you do any editing! I used to start editing before that was done, and my audio wouldn't match my video.

Comment: It's more like the original video footage was degraded while importing. the audio is good but the lips don't match.

It's like hearing "foot" but it looking like "oot"

Comment: My audio issue was different. I've never had degraded audio.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. The video was edited originally in Movie Maker and for some reason destroyed the quality. After I re-did everything all over again and only using Premiere, it cleared it all up.